# Serilog Net Core Additional Columns Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog SQL Server Sink for .NET Core 2.

I've configured `Serilog.Logger` in both the `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` like so:

```
ColumnOptions columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();

columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DataColumn>();
columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "UserId", DataType = typeof(string) });            
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()               
   .WriteTo.MSSqlServer("Data Source=TS-ABC\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=XYZ;Integrated Security=True",
    "ActivityLogs", columnOptions: columnOptions, autoCreateSqlTable: false, restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
.CreateLogger();
```

In `Sstartup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(x =>
{
    ColumnOptions columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();

    columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DataColumn>();                
    columnOptions.AdditionalDataColumns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "UserId", DataType = typeof(string) });

    return new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.MSSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"], Configuration["Serilog:TableName"], autoCreateSqlTable: false, columnOptions: columnOptions, restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug).CreateLogger();
});
```

`UserId` is of type `string` and allows null values. Also it's an FK in ActivityLogs table.

And this is how I'm logging information:

```
Log.Information("This has properties attached");
```

The code works fine as long as additional column `"UserId"` is added. The `UserId` column already exists in my database.

Here is the error which I can see in output window of Visual Studio:

> Unable to write 50 log events to the database due to following error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

After updating to `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer` nuget package now I'm receiving following error and nothing gets logged in DB.

> Unable to write 1 log events to the database due to following error: The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Any solution, hint or workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: _"The code works fine as long as additional column "UserId" is added. The UserId column already exists in my database."_ - so what is the problem?

Comment: @stuartd, I've updated the question.

Comment: Your question helped me solve a problem I was having. I was using Serilog.Sinks.MSSQLServerCore because I was under the impression that Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer was not compatible with .Net Core. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be reproducible. https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/96#issuecomment-417086438

Comment: I'm using Serilog.Settings.Configuration v2.5.0 and Serilog.AspNetCore v2.1.0. Are you using same version?

Comment: Try using the `dev` version of the _Configuration_ package (currently 3.0.0-dev00119), that's what I used in the repo I posted in the github issues thread (linked above). Please reply back in the github thread if this fixes your issue so we can close out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with not nullable additional columns with .net core. Set you field as Nullable.